# SQL Server Deadlock with Transaction Isolation Level Read Uncommitted

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

I am getting this deadlock even though I set the transaction level to uncommitted.  Is there something I am doing wrong? I thought I was suppose to get a dirty read here.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

   SELECT 
            DISTINCT 
            venueCourt.Id,
```

**Error**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 73) was deadlocked on thread | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Comment: Can you share more of the query? I'm wondering if there's something else affecting it. Also, if this is running in a stored procedure or trigger, the isolation level is temporary.

Comment: Actual execution plan please. Image is enough for a start.

Comment: SP, and lots of joins in query

Answer (score 0):

You can get deadlocks if the query goes parallel on you... although I'd be quite surprised with such a simple query.

Try adding OPTION (MAXDOP 1) at end of query.

Comment: Well the query isnt that simple, pretty complex, I just added the top of it

Comment: Can you explain what OPTION (MAXDOP 1) will do?

Comment: It forces SQL Server to only use one CPU core (no parallelism). Should clear up your deadlock if thats whats causing it.

Comment: Will it only do it for that query?  I'd like to keep parallelism if possible for other queries for performance reasons.